# How can I make this div block transition the same way as this website example

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to find the CSS that makes the Div block underneath launch website animate on this website:https://district2.studio/project/dafi/ - but can't seem to replicate the animation

I find in the style sheet

```
<div class="text__mask-wrap" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"<a class="post__title-launch d-inline-block" target="_blank" href="https://www.dafi.vn/">
                        <p class="mb-0">Launch Website</p>
                        <div class="launch__icon">
                            <span id="line-primary" class="line d-inline-block" style="width: 30px;"></span>
                            <span id="line-left" class="line d-block" style="opacity: 1; width: 0px;"></span>
                            <span id="line-right" class="line d-block" style="opacity: 1; width: 0px;"></span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

But can't find anything else in the html or css that relates back to this div block and animates it.

I was expecting some kind of transition but can't seem to find it.

I am building my first website and wanted to try out using this kind of div block animation.

```
<div class="text__mask-wrap" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"><a class="post__title-launch d-inline-block" target="_blank" href="https://www.dafi.vn/">
                        <p class="mb-0">Launch Website</p>
                        <div class="launch__icon">
                            <span id="line-primary" class="line d-inline-block" style="width: 30px;"></span>
                            <span id="line-left" class="line d-block" style="opacity: 1; width: 0px;"></span>
                            <span id="line-right" class="line d-block" style="opacity: 1; width: 0px;"></span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Whats expected is for the line to grow in width on mouse over, then mouse off it should grow from the middle and the 2 other lines should shrink to 0px in width

See the website launch website button for visual representation

Comment: Hello Evan please give me more infos on what you are looking so that i can help you. Is it the slideUp on the very beginning or what?

Comment: Hi @Gildas.Tambo its the launch website button. Looking for that line under it. If you mouse over it animates and thats what Im trying to figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use javascript code for this effect. if you jquery library added in your project, use this code:

```
$(".mb-0").hover(
function() {
    var elWidth = $(this).width();
    $(".launch__icon .line.d-inline-block").css({"width" : elWidth, "transition": "width 0.4s ease-out"});
    $(".launch__icon .line.d-block").css({"width" : (elWidth/2), "opacity":"0"});
}, function() {
    $(".launch__icon .line.d-inline-block").css({"width" : "30px", "transition": "width 0.4s ease-out", "transition-delay": "0.01s"});
    $(".launch__icon .line.d-block").css({"width" : "0", "opacity":"1", "transition": "width 0.45s ease-out"});
});
```

and use below css:

```
.launch__icon {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
height: 2px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 0;
}

.launch__icon #line-primary {
display: inline-block;
width: 30px;
height: 2px;
background: #fff;
}

.launch__icon #line-left {
left: 0;
}

.launch__icon #line-left,
.launch__icon #line-right {
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
background: #fff;
height: 2px;
top: 0;
opacity: 0;
}


.launch__icon #line-right {
right: 0;
}

.mb-0,
.my-0 {
 margin-bottom: 0!important
}

.d-inline-block {
display: inline-block!important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll have a go with this. Is this what is being used in the website?

Comment: for some reason can't get this to work still :( probably need to learn more about javascript

Comment: I tried to replicate it here: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=VAnQVV7xz5 What am I doing wrong? @Pegah

Comment: I couldn't open your link, this link redirect to new page. you can the answer here: https://jsfiddle.net/pegahkhf/0Lfa4zbw/3/

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

They are using javascript, but you can use css for that, here is an illustration:

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
/*
Since we want it to be centered i will use text-align center on the header which is just a wrapper
*/
header{
  text-align: center
}

/*because the children will be absolute, we need to set the anchor's position to relative*/
a{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
 
.underline{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 32px;
  margin-left: -16px;
  background-color: black;
  will-change: left,width;
  /*We need an elastic ease here*/
  transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.57, 0.67, 1.53);
}
a:hover .underline{
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 100%; 
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
a:before,
a:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: black;
  will-change: width;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
a:before{
  left: 0; 
}
a:after{
  right: 0;
}
a:hover:before,
a:hover:after{
  width: 50%;
  transition: all .2s .2s ease;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a>
    <p>Launch Website</p> 
    <span class="underline"> </span>
  </a>
<header>
```

Comment: This is great thank you! I think I understand this a bit more than I do javascript at the moment haha

Comment: i think that is what they wanted to achieve since the liquid animation occurs only when the sub-bar has reach the edges, even if you hover multiple times.